# Passing a pointer to multiple functions and memory allocation in first function

Tags: c, pointers, memory

My question is in the context of C programming and NOT C++!
I am trying to pass a pointer between multiple function. However the memory allocation should not be done by the caller. I tried a small example to simulate this. As can be seen, when the pointer points to a struct variable defined in main function, it is 'working' as expected. That is my function can manipulate the value in that memory address when the **value of the address** is passed. However when the function call returns and control passes on to main, why does the pointer get 'reinitialized'? Can the pointer somehow reflect the address that it was pointing to?

How can this be done?

Here is what I have:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

//example to pass a struct to void pointer and a void pointer to struct
//testing if memory allocation is done by callee and not caller

typedef struct mystructure{
    int a;
    char b;
    unsigned char c[10];
}mystruct;


void func(void *var){

    mystruct *s = var;
    s->a = 100;
    s->b = 'I';
    strncpy(s->c,"test",5);
    printf("In func\n");
    printf("s->a = %d\n",s->a);
    printf("s->b = %c\n",s->b);
    printf("s->c = %s\n",s->c);
}

void voidOut(void *var){

    mystruct *s = var;
    printf("In voidOut\n");
    printf("s->a = %d\n",s->a);
    printf("s->b = %c\n",s->b);
    printf("s->c = %s\n",s->c);

}

//here is void pointer is both and 'in' and 'out' parameter
void memfunc(void *var){

    mystruct *s = var;
    s = (mystruct *)malloc(sizeof(mystruct));
    s->a = 100;
    s->b = 'I';
    printf("In memfunc\n");
    strncpy(s->c,"test",5);
    printf("s->a = %d\n",s->a);
    printf("s->b = %c\n",s->b);
    printf("s->c = %s\n",s->c);
}

//here is void pointer is an 'in' parameter
void memvoidOut(void *var){

    mystruct *s = var;
    printf("In memvoidOut\n");
    printf("s->a = %d\n",s->a);
    printf("s->b = %c\n",s->b);
    printf("s->c = %s\n",s->c);
}


int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    mystruct val;
    func(&val);
    voidOut(&val);

    mystruct *ptr = NULL;
    memfunc(ptr);
    memvoidOut(ptr);

    return 0;
}
```

UPDATE:
Following the answers and comments, here is what I have:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

//example to pass a struct to void pointer and a void pointer to struct
//testing if allocation is done by callee and not caller

typedef struct mystructure{
    int a;
    char b;
    unsigned char c[10];
}mystruct;


void func(void *var){

    mystruct *s = var;
    s->a = 100;
    s->b = 'I';
    strncpy(s->c,"test",5);
    printf("In func\n");
    printf("s->a = %d\n",s->a);
    printf("s->b = %c\n",s->b);
    printf("s->c = %s\n",s->c);
}

void voidOut(void *var){

    mystruct *s = var;
    printf("In voidOut\n");
    printf("s->a = %d\n",s->a);
    printf("s->b = %c\n",s->b);
    printf("s->c = %s\n",s->c);

}


//here is void pointer is both and 'in' and 'out' parameter
void memfunc(void **var){

    mystruct *s = var;
    s = (mystruct *)malloc(sizeof(mystruct));
    s->a = 100;
    s->b = 'I';
    printf("In memfunc\n");
    strncpy(s->c,"test",5);
    printf("s->a = %d\n",s->a);
    printf("s->b = %c\n",s->b);
    printf("s->c = %s\n",s->c);
    //memcpy(var,s, sizeof(s));
}

//here is void pointer is an 'in' parameter
void memvoidOut(void **var){

    mystruct *s = var;
    printf("In memvoidOut\n");
    printf("s->a = %d\n",s->a);
    printf("s->b = %c\n",s->b);
    printf("s->c = %s\n",s->c);
}


int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    mystruct val;
    func(&val);
    voidOut(&val);

    mystruct *ptr = NULL;
    memfunc(&ptr);
    memvoidOut(&ptr);

    return 0;
}
```

However my output is:

```
In func
s->a = 100
s->b = I
s->c = test
In voidOut
s->a = 100
s->b = I
s->c = test
In memfunc
s->a = 100
s->b = I
s->c = test
In memvoidOut
s->a = 0
s->b = d
s->c =
```

What am I missing? Shoud I define memory for the struct in memvoidOut?

Comment: Why are you using void pointers?

Comment: When I explicitly do I memcpy(var,s,sizeof(s)) in memfunc, it works. However I would like to understand what is really happening

Comment: I want to hide my structure later for developing an API

Comment: Why not change `void memfunc(void *var)` to `void *memFunc()....return s;`

Comment: Actually I should later use integers as return values to return just error codes....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should change the signature of the function that allocates the new memory:

```
void memfunc(void *var)
```

to

```
void memfunc(void **var)
```

and call from main

```
memfunc(&ptr)
```

Explanation:

Your memfunc function, makes a copy of the passed pointer ptr. Initially, it assigns this pointer to the allocated space (via malloc), but then, after the function returns, the pointer is still the original one that was passed to memfunc (that is NULL) because that ptr pointer's copy was reclaimed.

Now if you change it as proposed, the address of the pointer will be passed, thus you will not face that "copy pointer" issue

Comment: Thanks but I just added a comment: 
 
When I explicitly do I memcpy(var,s,sizeof(s)) in memfunc, it works

Comment: memcpy has nothing to do with your function. It is a tottaly different approach

Comment: Oh I see. thanks for pointing out that the pointer passed is a copy!! That explains

Comment: Np, happy to help :)

Comment: Is there a way to keep the signature of the function constant and somehow see to that the address is passed??

Comment: Constant as it is I don't think so (void * would always make a copy out of the passed pointer). You can do a lot of dirty hacks, such as keeping the address of the pointer in a long int , and assign some space directly to this (memory stored as long int). But why would you do that?? The usual way to do this is as proposed (actually this is the best because you can keep return values for error codes), or return the void* allocated memory

Comment: As a last comment, if I change to void**, can I use the variable that is pointed to that it is both in and out parameter??

Comment: In parameter meaning that you want to pass something other than null? And make some calculations before assigning new memory to it? Yes that should be doable too.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101287/discussion-between-user489152-and-sestus).

Answer (score 1):

Function arguments are passed by value in C.  So, you cannot pass the pointer itself and allocate memory *to* the pointer itself from the called function.

You can do either of two things

1. Pass the address of the pointer to allocated memory from another function.
2. Pass the pointer, allocate memory, return the allocated pointer from the function and in the caller, collect the return value in the same pointer.

So, in case of `memfunc()`, either

- You have to change the signature to pass `&ptr`, collect in `mystruct **var` and then, inside the function, allocate memory for `*var`
- You need to return a `mystruct *` and collect that in `ptr`.

Comment: In void memfunc(void *var) I was hoping to somehow keep the var parameter as both the 'input' and 'output' parameter

Comment: Sourav Ghosh, could you please explain the second method. Can I keep the returned structure in the void pointer itself. Can you please elaborate